# Is it possible to get actual cropped PNG from Croppie instead of the base64 encoding?

Tags: base64, crop, image-conversion

I am using Croppie to crop an image and it is giving me base64 which creates 413 error while sending it on server for large images, so I need proper image file. I tried to find converting it(base64) as a image file locally at client side but didn't get expected way for conversion using javascript/jquery.

Please guide me.